Novel where a girl finds a book of drawings (I think from someone in a coma) and it inspires her and her friends to do criminal art
I think I read this around 2020. I can vividly recall where I was when I was reading it, an event space next to my town's pool and community library (I was completing reading the book so I could check it in). There's a decent chance that I was going for a walk midday, which likely means it happened in the 2020-2021 time frame when I'd been laid off and was between jobs (and before the birth of my toddler son who now occupies a lot of free time). The viewpoint is a teenage girl, who finds a sketchbook full of drawings. I believe the owner of the book was a boy who'd had an accident and was in a coma. I don't recall if she was aware of that. Something about the book (and maybe general teenage dissatisfaction) led to her embarking on a series of guerilla art projects, sometimes with the help of her friends. Unfortunately, I don't really remember the content of the art projects other than that I think one involved little people posed in a tableau. The local government views her art projects as vandalism and/or the beginnings of something like a gang or terrorist cell, and start imposing curfews and stepping up surveillance and patrols. The book was set in the United States, somewhere in the late 20th to the early 21st century, and had no fantasy or science fiction aspects (this was not a dystopia book, just small town government fighting a baffling trend). I think she'd started inspiring other people to do the same, maybe involving a child getting injured while doing their project (my brain wants to say a broken leg). Her final project had something to do with a clocktower in town that I think had unstable/damaged floors, and she winds cornered there and surrendering to the police.
Around the end of the book, the boy whose sketchbook she found awakes from her coma, and she gets a chance to talk with him, and to return his book.

Looking through my library history, I'm thinking this may be a slightly confused memory of The Plain Janes by Cecil Castellucci and Jim Rugg. Summary from this review.


This book wanted to have heart. The premise started off really good. Jane is at a coffee shop when a bomb goes off. She is traumatized by the event but the only thing that keeps her hanging on is a stranger she helped keep safe during the attack. The stranger has been in a coma and no one knows who he is. Jane however visits him everyday and reads to him. Her mother is so terrified of losing Jane after the event that the whole family moves to a small town, hoping to hide and stay safe from the chaos of the world.
Jane goes from becoming the beautiful, blond girl next door to chopping off her hair and dying it black. She is invited to join the popular girls' lunch table the first day of school but something in Jane has changed and she rejects them, choosing instead to join a table of three misfit girls, all named Theater Jane, Brainy Jayne, and Polly Jane. So far so good.
Jane decides to create a secret club, P.L.A.I.N. (People Loving Art in Neighborhoods). The girls sneak out at night and create art that not everyone is happy about. The police is trying to nab the vandals who are destroying the neighborhood, while the Janes think they are saving lives with their art form. This is where the book fell flat for me. I wasn't buying this whole Art Saves concept and I wasn't impressed enough to believe their art was having some magical effect on the town. In fact, you never really see how the town is affected by this, other than the chief of police who has made finding the culprits his personal agenda.

It has the guy in a coma and guerilla art. One of the other reviews mentions them feeling the sourcing of so many garden gnomes to be unbelievable, which would match with my memory of one of the art pieces involving a bunch of "little people". I don't remember this being a graphic novel, but it matches too well.
Looking at a copy (unavailable to borrow, likely due to the current legal battle) on the Internet Archive, it looks like the climactic art stunt is at a clock tower.

